# PodFile not installing specified version

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am using CocoaPods to install a specific version of `AFNetworking`. My podfile is as follows :

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '7.0'
target "WGCore" do
pod 'XMPPFramework'
pod 'AFNetworking’, ’2.3.1’
pod 'FMDB'
pod 'Reachability'', '3.1'
end
target "WGCoreTests" do
end
```

My installation command is `pod install --verbose --no-repo-update`

I have tried deleting the cache for pods.
I have tried deleting the podlock.
But no matter what, I am still getting `AFNetworking 3.1.0`.
This is my first time using `CocoaPods`. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @NikKov Unfortunately not working

Comment: What version of cocoapods are you using? And is your cocoapods running using the new/ sharded repository layout of cocoapods? (e.g. cd into your `~/.cocoapods/repos/master` and run `git pull`?

Comment: My cocoapod version is 0.39

Comment: `pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.3.1` doesn't work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[About installing specific version](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html)

[image: no descr]

Other words you're doing right. It can be a problem with 2.3.1 (try ~>2) or (< 3). Maybe this version doen't work with ios, '7.0', only with lower version. Use just `pod install`. Try to [reinstall](https://superuser.com/questions/686317/how-to-fully-uninstall-the-cocoapods-from-the-mac-machine) cocoapods. After uninstalling use `gem cleanup`.

You can install [manually](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/releases/tag/2.3.1) or use specific commit in cocoapods (81d54e5)

Comment: Last cocoapods version is 1.1.1 so you didn't reinstall it, othercase it should download the newest one.

Comment: I installed the latest version, was still causing problems but upgrading to the beta worked. I will mark this as the correct answer. Thanks.